# Composite Key EF Core getting error when using Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

So I have the following class in Entity Framework Core. I am trying to do a code first migration and can't for the life of me figure out how to make the fluent API for this work.

```
public class Participants
{
    public Activity Activity { get; set; } //Class with Id and Name of Activity
    public ApplicationUser Participant { get; set; } 

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ParticipantId { get; set; }
}
```

In EF6 I was able to do this in OnModelCreating to get it to work fine.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Attendance>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Activity)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But in EF Core I get

> " Entity type 'Participants' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API."

I have tried using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Participants>().HasKey(p => new {p.Activity, p.Participant});
```

But, that just leads to

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Participants_AspNetUsers_ParticipantId' on table 'Participants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

If there is a better way to do the whole thing I'm open to suggestions. If you have pluralsight subscription, I'm basically trying to get "Become a Full Stack Developer" by Mosh Hamedani to work in EF core. The example is in "13-full-stack-fundamentals" folder.

UPDATE: Also tried

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Participants>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Activity)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Still got

> "Entity type 'Participants' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API."

UPDATE 2: After trying Roy's suggestion this is what I'm getting

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Participants_AspNetUsers_ParticipantId' on table 'Participants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

UPDATE 3: In the Migration

I removed one of the OneDelete: ReferntialAction.Cascade and it worked. I removed the one off of FK_Participants_AspNetUsers_ParticipantId.

I also changed to this in my OnModelCreating

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Participants>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.ActivityId, p.ParticipantId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Added this ( Not sure if it's needed if anyone knows let me know) 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Participants>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Activity)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: what happens if you define the relationship between Participants and ApplicationUser (Participant) in a similar way to modelBuilder.Entity<Attendance>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Activity)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); ?

Comment: Updated to show what else I tried.

Comment: Can you share `Activity` type? Are you certain that you are not introducing a cyclic path? If that the case then you should not need to remove anything from migration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are trying to do is create a relationship between Activity and Participant which is a little different in EFCore.

To do it, you would need to reference the ForeignKey Properties instead of NavigationProperties in the modelbuilder as follows:

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<Participants>()
        .HasKey(p => new { p.ActivityId , p.ParticipantId });
```

Comment: @vgwizardx Didn't understand your update, did your changes fixed the issue?

Comment: Yeah, they fixed what happened after I made your change. I guess what happens in the migration is it creates a double cascade path. So you have to remove one of the cascade paths to make things work completely.

Comment: While this answer may have solved the issue, the reasoning is incorrect. Composite PK definition using data annotation is not allowed in EF core and must be specified using fluent API. This is true regardless of any navigation or relationship. In above code, even if there were no navigations, it would still throw exception for composite PK.